# Como Hago que al imprimir los datos, el ciclo lo haga por columnas y no por filas- JAVA

Tags: java, netbeans, bucle-for, netbeans-8.2, netbeans-11.2

tengo el siguiente codigo:

```
        String datos="13 28 29 26 19 27 20 12 16 11";
         
        int contador=1;
        int contadorAux=0;
        for(String dato: aux.split("\t")){
            contadorAux++;
            System.out.print(dato+" ");
            if(contador==contadorAux){
                
                System.out.println();
                contador++;
                contadorAux=0;
            }

        }
```

Lo que sucede es que cuando lo ejecuto me imprime esto:

```
13 
28 29 
26 19 27 
20 12 16 11
```

Y necesito que me lo imprima los datos que va recibiendo en columnas y no en filas, que salga asi:

```
13 
28 19 
29 27 20 
26 12 16 11
```

Gracias de antemano.

Answer (score 0):

Quizás no sea lo más performante, pero para visualizarlo, yo colocaría esos valores en una matriz de 4 x 4, y despues despues con dos `for` anidados recorrería la matriz e imprimiería los elementos fila por fila como están en la matriz.

Tip: los espacios en blanco los pondría como -1, y cuando imprimo, si encuentro un -1, imprimo un espacio en blanco.